# Is there a way to check if the script is running by PowerShell ISE?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to skip the Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript lines if the PowerShell script is running by Powersehll ISE.

Is this possible? And how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do:

```
if ($host.name -eq 'ConsoleHost') # or -notmatch 'ISE'
{
  .. do something .. 
}
else
{
  .. do something else..
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Know this was asked quite a while ago, and already marked as answered, but one more way:

```
function Test-IsISE {
# try...catch accounts for:
# Set-StrictMode -Version latest
    try {    
        return $psISE -ne $null;
    }
    catch {
        return $false;
    }
}
```

`$psISE` is available in ISE: [The ISE Object Model Hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/object-model/the-ise-object-model-hierarchy?view=powershell-5.1).

Answer (score 10):

Here's a method that looks for the existance of `$psISE` without generating exceptions:

```
if (Test-Path variable:global:psISE)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative...

```
Try {
    Start-Transcript -Path <somepath> | Out-Null
}

Catch [System.Management.Automation.PSNotSupportedException] {
    # The current PowerShell Host doesn't support transcribing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These are great answers!  Here is a way that I use $host.name

I needed a way to:

Use ReadKey in my script (which will NOT work in ISE) but still be able to use (and run) the script with the Powershell ISE.
Have a way for the script to know whether it is in Console or ISE and activate ReadKey or Read-Host respectively.

Here is the code for that:

```
IF ($host.name -eq 'Windows Powershell ISE Host') {$K = Read-Host "Please make your choice"} #Used when you are in ISE.  Will necessitate an ENTER Key.
IF ($host.name -eq 'ConsoleHost') {$KeyPress = [System.Console]::ReadKey();$K = $KeyPress.Key} #Used when running in Console. This will NOT necessitate an ENTER Key. BUT, it ## will NOT work ## in ISE
```